# Hibernate plugin en Netbeans 11 genera hibernate.hbm.xml que no puede ser parseado

Tags: hibernate, netbeans-11

Estoy utilizando Netbeans 11.0 con el plugin de Hibernate.
Cuando realizo Hibernate Mapping Wizard para generar una tabla desde una entidad, se genera el siguiente hibernate.hbm.xml

```
`<hibernate-mapping>
  <class dynamic-insert="false" 
  dynamic-update="false" mutable="true" 
  name="com.proof.hbmaven01.domain.Player" 
  optimistic-lock="version" polymorphism="implicit" 
  select-before-update="false"/>
</hibernate-mapping>`
```

Al ejecutar el programa recibo el siguiente error

```
 Could not parse mapping document:  hibernate.hbm.xml...
    Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.MappingException:
 Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 45 and column 90. Message:
cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: El contenido del elemento 'class' no está completo. 
Se esperaba uno de 

    http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/hbm":meta, 
    . . . 
    http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/hbm":tuplizer, 
    http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/hbm":id, 
    http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/hbm":composite-i
```

Utilicé el siguiente tutorial 
http://wiki.netbeans.org/HibernateMappingWizard

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Ese plugin es antiguo y no ha sido actualizado desde hace años.
Así que utilizando la opción, mostrada a continuación, en la creación de tipos de ficheros

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se consiguen básicamente las mismas opciones que el plugin Hibernate
Saludos